# Why do some cameras offer 5-axis stabilization only in video?

Tags: image-processing, video, image-stabilization

The new EOS M6, not surely FZ2000 etc. offer 5-axis image stabilization only when shooting video. Why is that?; I think it takes more processing power to do such thing in video mode though...

Answer (score 1):

This (the 5-axis image stabilization the M6 offers) is a digital stabilization, which works by rotating/shifting the image from frame to frame (presumably based on image content as post processors do it, maybe on gyrosensors).  This only really makes sense for multiple frames, i.e. video.

Still images profit from optical stabilization built into lenses for Canon. Some other systems provide sensor-shift optical stabilization in the body, like Sony. This will yield a much better image quality, which is more important for stills than video.

Comment: Mind that there is also image stabilization with some cameras, where it is build into the body itself. Those cameras move the sensor physically to achieve a stable image.

Comment: Yes, that is also optical stabilization, but not in this case, which is why it's only for video.

Comment: @ths So 5-axis IS is always **not** a sensor shift method?

Comment: @user152435 No, there are cameras, like Olympus OM-D E1, that got 5 axis sensor shift (still and video)

Comment: And, does the [FZ1000](https://www.dpreview.com/products/panasonic/compacts/panasonic_dmcfz1000/specifications) support 5-axis IS when shooting stills? What about that?

Comment: @NicoHarms But ths says 5-axis IS **is** (always?) a digital stabilization and hence it can only be done in video?

Comment: No, i said that the kind of digital stabilization the M6 offers, is for video. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @NicoHarms It is with the Canon M6. It isn't with *some* (but not all) other models.

Comment: @NicoHarms: the FZ1000 claims to have "Hybrid O.I.S" and 5-axis stabilization. "O.I.S" means "optical image stabilization". It's anyone's guess what "hybrid" means here. Anyway, you'll get stabilization for stills, of whatever technology. It's not an ILC, so there's one less worry.

Comment: @MichaelClark, ths: I just wanted to point out, that also optical, in body, IS exists. The initial revision was less specific and read as if in body stabilization is always digital, at least for me. Thank you for clarification.